# How do I remove a broken toilet auger from my toilet?

Tags: plumbing, tools, toilet, clog

My toilet is suffering frequent clogs that could be cleared with a plunger, but recurs  the next time we send anything down.

So I went and got the fanciest toilet auger at Lowe's, [Cobra brand heavy duty "drop head" (model 47030)](http://www.lowes.com/pd_100799-319-47030-2_0__?productId=4775375).

I got it to go down about 18 inches, and then it got jammed.  I tried reversing the twist, and the snake part became detached from the handle.

After much back and forth, I eventually got the snake out.  I have two issues:

1. Is there any special technique for reconnecting the handle?  Should I consider it defective?
2. It still clogs very easily.  Is it time to pull the toilet?  Or would a narrower auger snake be worth a try?

Comment: Have you gotten on the roof to see if the vent is clogged?

Comment: I've been on the roof, and I sent my normal drain snake down.  The toilet is only 3 feet from the main exit of the building.  There is not much of a horizontal run at all.  Plus it is easily fixed by plunging.  I've plunged about 30 times.

Comment: For those of you following along, I got the slinky part of the snake out by putting on the gloves.  It gave me more control than that 3foot handle.  I used the L-shaped tube that was left over to guide a regular drain snake, and that helped loosen things up.